# Route an incoming ICMP packet to a different interface/process

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, nat, icmp

I have an interface `enp4s0` with several IPs.
I get `ICMP` packets (type 8, echo request) from external device to my device on `enp4s0`.
I'm trying to route only packets sent to `192.168.1.90` into another interface on the same device.    On that interface there's a process which should handle these packets.

```
7: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:08:11:22:33:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.174/24 metric 1024 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp4s0
       valid_lft 2556122sec preferred_lft 2556122sec
    inet 192.168.1.90/24 scope global secondary enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::208:a2ff:fe0c:f648/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The interface I'm trying to route to is a `tap` interface which was added like this:

```
ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap
ip link set dev tap0 up
ip addr add 128.1.3.2/24 dev tap0
```

I have a little program which `read()`s from that interface.  Because this program is running, the interface state is UP:

```
80: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7a:0e:b7:37:f4:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 128.1.3.2/24 scope global tap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::780e:b7ff:fe37:f474/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My intention is, that my app that reads from `tap0` will answer the `ICMP` packets.
Using `tcpdump` and looking at my app's output, I can see traffic when I inject some packets using `tcpreplay` directly (`tcpreplay -i tap0 ...`)

Back to the routing -
I'm trying to route using:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p icmp -j DNAT --to-destination 128.1.3.2
```

Note: the above `iptables` rule is a simplified form of what I'm trying to have (only `icmp` type 8, only packets with specific `dst address`, only from specific input interface. This is because I'm trying to first make it work).

This is the current routing table:

```
 ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp4s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.174 metric 1024 
...
128.1.3.0/24 dev tap0 proto kernel scope link src 128.1.3.2 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.174 metric 1024 
192.168.1.1 dev enp4s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.174 metric 1024
```

What I expected from all the above, is that all `ICMP` packets would get routed to the `tap0` interface, which doesn't work.
When `ICMP`s are sent, I get reply immediately.
Looking at `iptables -t nat -L -vnx` I see my rules work, meaning there are hits on the above `iptables` rule.
But there's nothing on `iptables -L FORWARD -vnx` (default policy is `ACCEPT`).
Looking at `iptables -L INPUT -vnx` I can see the packets accepted.

Please help - is it possible to do this routing?

Answer (score 0):

OK.
I re-read [Forwarding ICMP response to TAP interface](https://serverfault.com/questions/959778/forwarding-icmp-response-to-tap-interface) and now I understand the answer:

> What does matter is the route to the TAP interface. That is, because of the implicit route added when the interface is brought up, any IP in 10.0.4.0/24 except 10.0.4.1.

```
# ip route get 10.0.4.1
local 10.0.4.1 dev lo src 10.0.4.1 uid 0 
    cache <local> 
# ip route get 10.0.4.2
10.0.4.2 dev tap0 src 10.0.4.1 uid 0 
    cache
```

Anyway. I changed my `iptables` rule to a different IP, on the same subnet as `tap0` and now it works!
Thanks @A.B